# Utilizar codigo android en projecto de netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans

Estoy utilizando netbeans 8.2 y el caso es simple, estoy realizando un proyecto multi-plataforma, se ejecuta como servicio, porque es un reproductor de música que se controla mediante un servicio web. Cuando lo llevo a android, utilizando este proyecto como dependencia para una aplicación de android studio,  al importarlo necesito utilizar un comando de android, el problema es que no logro encontrar el "import" correcto. Estoy en una clase de una app java. El comando es este :

> getExternalFilesDir()

Este comando lo ejecutaría si la plataforma actual seria android, y estoy ingresando este comando en la clase de base de datos.
entonces, necesitaria el import para ejecutar este comando, necesito agregar alguna libreria? y que import debo utilizar
Es una pregunta sencilla pero no consigo la respuesta! espero si puede alguien decirme gracias!

PD: para verificar si es el sistema android, verifico si existe la clase main activity de mi proyecto

```
public static boolean isandroid() {
         try {
        Class.forName("sistema.main.mainactivity");
        return true;
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Procura añadir código e información cuando preguntes, de esta forma tu pregunta sería mas útil a muchis desarrolladores y la comunidad, revisar [ask]. ¿estas en un fragment o activity?

Comment: hola jorge, te cuento que el proyecto no esta en el activity sino que lo que hago es importarlo como dependencia de un proyecto android studio, el proyecto se ejecuta como servicio, porque es un reproductor de musica que se controla mediante un servicio web,

Comment: "Este comando lo ejecutaría si la plataforma actual seria android", que plataforma usas? , el método que comentas es propio del sdk android.

Comment: es algo como if (isandroid()){ lo que hace es verificar si existe el main activity , entonces si es android, sino estaria el activity no seria android, seria linux o windows etc.